# Trying to write salary program, error in Convert.toDouble

Tags: c#

I can't seem to get this working - having an error on line `double weekly_salary = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[3]);`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CompanyPayAndExpense
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public double CalculateNetPay(double weekly_salary, double expense1, double expense2)
        {
            double basic_pay = 0.0; ;
            double extra_pay = 0.0;
            double net_pay = 0.0;

            if (weekly_salary > 550)
            {
                basic_pay = 550;
                extra_pay = weekly_salary - basic_pay;
            }
            else
            {
                basic_pay = weekly_salary;
                extra_pay = 0.0;
            }

            double tax = basic_pay * 0.2 + extra_pay * 0.4;

            net_pay = weekly_salary + expense1 + expense2 - tax;
            return net_pay;
        }


        private void cbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myEmployees = cbEmployees.SelectedItem.ToString();
            lbEmployees.Items.Clear();

            string[] lineOfContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Employees.csv");

            foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
            {
                string[] tokens = line.Split(',');


                if (tokens [0] == myEmployees)
                {
                    lbEmployees.Items.Add(tokens[1]);               }
            }
        }

        private void lbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] lineOfContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Employees.csv");
            foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
            {
                string[] tokens = line.Split(',');

                if (tokens[1] == (string)lbEmployees.SelectedItem) ;
                { 
                  double  weekly_salary = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[3]);
                  double  expense1 = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[4]);
                   double  expense2 = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[5]);

                    lblEmployees.Text = "€" + CalculateNetPay(weekly_salary, expense1, expense2).ToString();
                }
            }
        }



            }

        }
```

.csv content

```
Role,Name,PPS,weekly_salary,expense1,expense2
Engineer,Paul Smith,9018731G,700,220,90
Engineer,Gary Murphy,5018473F,650,190,130
Engineer, Peter Tate, 3108318A, 725, 300, 200
Manager, Larry O'Dwyer, 4012881N, 900, 450, 85
Manager, John O'Connor, 7012812Q, 1100, 360, 75
Assistant Manager, Ryan Smith, 8847233P, 800, 125, 135
Assistant Manager, Mary Leane, 7887323D, 820, 170, 160
Operative, Olivia Mulcahy, 8732432S, 450, 50, 40
Operative, Sarah Buckley, 8923439J, 390, 70, 30
Sales Executive, Ken Wilkins, 7438432D, 560, 110, 110
Sales Executive, Simon McCann, 2382112Y, 610, 140, 200
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't just post your code and expect someone to find the issue and fix it for you. You should boil the code down to the minimal code required to reproduce the problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You also don't state what the problem you are having is, are you getting an error ( if so what is the error) or an unexpected result (what result are you expecting and what value are you getting).

Comment: Sorry. New to this im gett in and error on line  double  weekly_salary = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[3]);

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Use the edit button below your question to add this information to your question, and as per my previous comment also try to remove any code not required to show this error.

Comment: I would highly suggest that you pinpoint where the issue is happening by using the debugger.. this is what coding is about.. learn to use the tools that are at your disposal..

Comment: Thamks guys. Im sorry for being a noob. Im just learning the ropes and this is a part of my second project in C# . I have understood everything Im doing apart from this little part Im just having trouble with.

Comment: Noob or not this is part of coding which is learning if you take the time to step through the code you can understand what's going on.. please try that first .. and tell us where in the code you are not seeing results as expected..

Comment: the problem appears to be caused by a stray `;` after the if statement that is causing the convert to double to be run against the header row which ofcourse cannot be converted to a double.

Comment: @MethodMan that is the PPS column, not the weekly_salary

Comment: good catch ..too many edit changes to the original question

Comment: Oh that is similar to Social security number @MethodMan.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my previous answer because an edit to the question has made the issue clear and my old answer has become redundant.

in your csv data it is clear that after some commas there are spaces before values, this means that you are trying to convert - for example - `450` into a double, even though it is preceded by a space, as such you should trim the values like so

```
double  weekly_salary = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[3].Trim());
double  expense1 = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[4].Trim());
double  expense2 = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[5].Trim());
```

It would also be slightly better to do a for loop instead of a foreach, as it will mean you skip the top row (titles)

```
for (int i = 1; i < lineOfContents.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    //AllTheCode
}
```

This also means that instead of using `line.Split(',');` you have to use `lineOfContents[i].Split(',');`

Comment: Hi, everyone thanks for your help. I can t beleive I missed that. You are also right that coding is about learnig and doing you own work before coming here. Thanks @Alfie . I would like to see the othe code you put up if possible if you think it was more effient. Thanks

Comment: I will add the extra part to this answer

Comment: @finbarrdonnelly did that actually fix your problem? Im curious because I wrote a quick test that was able to convert a value with leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it was causing your error but I do see one rather impactful bug with your code:

```
if (tokens[1] == (string)lbEmployees.SelectedItem) ; // This semicolon should not be here
{ 
    double  weekly_salary = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[3]);
    double  expense1 = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[4]);
    double  expense2 = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[5]);

    lblEmployees.Text = "€" + CalculateNetPay(weekly_salary, expense1, expense2).ToString();
}
```

The semicolon that I commented in the code above is actually ending your `if` statement early, so the code block following it will be  run regardless of your `if` statement passing, which can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: I think that was just an error putting the code into the question box, as they use if statements elsewhere in their code. But if this really is a mistake on their part, it is definitely worth pointing out

Comment: @alfie I wasn't sure if that was the case. As I stated in a comment on your answer I wrote a quick test that lead me to believe the spaces weren't causing the error so I felt I should post this just in case. The test for reference `var val = Convert.ToDouble("  740"); Assert.That(val, Is.EqualTo(740));`

Comment: @ Phaeze Yes the semicolon was the problem I was having. I shouldnt have missed it. But I will add the more efficient additions that Alfie has provided also. Great!